# How to unbind by `trigger` event

Tags: jquery, triggers

I would like to suspend a binding a point of variable as a decalaration as `false`. i tried with couple of way, but not works

any one help me?

here is my code :

```
$(document).on('suspendSelection', this.suspendSelection.bind(this));
$(document).on('updateSelection', this.beforeStartSelect.bind(this)); //require to suspend when i get suspend selection triggered!
```

my try:

```
suspendSelection : function () {

    $.unbind('updateSelection', this.beforeStartSelect.bind(this)); //not works
}
suspendSelection : function () {
            this.Update.unbind('updateSelection', this.beforeStartSelect.bind(this)) //not works
        },
```

Comment: you registered an event handler on document for `updateSelection` event and now you wan't remove that handler when there's a `suspendSelection` event on the document. Is that what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you registered some event handler on some element using on() method, then you can simply remove it using off()

```
 $(document).on('updateSelection', this.beforeStartSelect.bind(this));
 $(document).on('suspendSelection', this.suspendSelection.bind(this));
```

just update your suspendSelection() like this,

```
suspendSelection : function(){
   /* select the same element, call off() passing the event to 
      remove and the handler function you used while registering*/
   $(document).off('updateSelection', this.beforeStartSelect.bind(this));
}
```

Hope this helps :)